# Latest nodejs is not installing

Tags: node.js, nodes

I'm trying to install latest nodejs but it's installing 4.4.0 version. I 
   try to install from PPA. Every newest version is not installing. I'm 
   using ubuntu 16.04 32 bit OS.

Any solution guys?

Comment: What are the commands you are using in order to install nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues before. I fixed it by installing node via the Node Version Manager (nvm).

First run:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.0/install.sh | bash
```

Then:

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Then:

```
nvm install 11.1.0
```

replacing 11.1.0 with whichever version is latest at the time.

Then check with:

```
node -v
```